# How to write in laravel subquery?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, subquery

I have mysql query and now need to convert it into subquery.How can I do?

```
SELECT DATE(dateCreated) AS 'date' , SUM(amount) AS newPay FROM transaction_logs WHERE DATE(dateCreated) 
>= '2022-10-01' AND DATE(dateCreated) 
<= '2022-10-05' AND phone IN (SELECT phone FROM users) GROUP BY DATE(dateCreated)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ModelName::select('dateCreated as date')
->sum('amount as newPay')
->whereBetween('dateCreated', ['2022-10-01','2022-10-05'])
->whereHas('user_phone')
->groupBy('dateCreated')->get(); //or ->paginate();
```

At the Model create a phone_users method like:

```
 public function user_phone(): BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'phone', 'phone');
    }
```